# Swapping from Windows 7 to Ubuntu (host) and Windows 7 VM on same hardware

Tags: windows-7, windows, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

This may have been asked elsewhere, but it always seems to be unclear about whether they are staying on exactly the same physical hardware.

I have Windows 7 32bit with lots of programs installed (inc MS Office) and I am happy with it with one exception, RAM. To have more RAM I would need to go 64bit. Any route I see to 64bit Windows involves a clean install and loss of (or at least hassle to get back) my installed programs.

So, the approach that comes to mind is to migrate my Windows 7 from physical to VM and use VirtualBox (or other) under a 64bit host OS. I can then only use Windows 7's limited RAM for doing things I can only do there and everything else is done in the 64bit host OS.

Windows 10 upgrade is freely available to me at the moment, but I expect that would count as two installs (Win7 guest under Win10 host) so not be allowed under the license.

I'm happy using Ubuntu and so could have one install of Windows running on the very same hardware as before, but under a VM in Ubuntu 64bit host OS.

The big question that remains is has anyone done this and will I be able to re-activate Windows 7 (and MS Office) in the VM (on the same physical hardware as before). I did a dry run cloning my HDD to VHD and running the resulting Windows 7 VM on the same Windows 7 host (a bit of a mind twister that) and it said it wasn't genuine and implied I have to reactivate, but I don't want to do that as it will probably kill the activation of my currently still host Windows 7.

Thoughts on legality and practicality. I don't think MS would ever break down my door and haul me in front of a judge for running Windows 7 on the same hardware as before, but in a VM. So really it boils down to the activation, will MS let me activate?